# How to bypass iOS Permission policy for Audio element .play() method?

Tags: javascript, ios, webkit

There is a button, by pressing which the sound is played without problems, but the problem is that it is necessary to output subsequent sounds further, but without pressing the playback start button. But the browser gives Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError.

Does anyone know a way to get around this limitation?

Comment: How are you triggering subsequent sounds? On a timer? Please provide some code if possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#:%7E:text=the%20JavaScript%20play()%20and%20load()%20methods%20are%20also%20inactive%20until%20the%20user%20initiates%20playback%2C%20unless%20the%20play()%20or%20load()%20method%20is%20triggered%20by%20user%20action):

> the JavaScript `play()` and `load()` methods are also inactive until the user initiates playback, unless the `play()` or `load()` method is triggered by user action.

In other words, the browser will not download the audio file unless it's requested during a user-initiated event, such as clicking a button, in order to minimize data usage. However, once a user action downloads the audio, `play()` can be called arbitrarily to resume playback.

As a result, when the user presses the button to play the first sound, you should call `play()` followed immediately by `pause()`, on each audio element; this downloads all the audio files and enables them to be played by any subsequent JavaScript, without further user action.

```js
onclick = () => {
  audios.forEach(audio => { audio.play(); audio.pause(); })
}
```